# Timestamp calculation function

Tags: java

I am trying to write Java code as a part of my project to get current time for a process and then i need to add a fixed timeout period to it. This new time has to be compared with my above currenttime and take decision based on that. I am not able to add time to the currenttime and compare it. Can anyone help me by suggesting a way?

This is my code:

```
   public class SessionDetails
    {
     public String getCurrentUtcTimestamp() {
        TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC:00");
        DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance();
        dateFormat.setTimeZone(timeZone);
        timeStamp = dateFormat.format(new Date());
        return timeStamp;
    }
     public void createSession()
         {
           int value = getsession();
           String timeStamp = getCurrentUtcTimestamp() ;
           System.out.println("New session Details :");
           System.out.println("session value:" + value);
           System.out.println("Time of creation :" + timeStamp );
         }
    public boolean checkTimeout(int value)
        {   
            private static long c_Timeout = 10000;
            String currentTime =  getCurrentUtcTimestamp() ;
            if ( currentTime > timeStamp + c_Timeout )   //failing to implement this logic efficiently .please do suggest a way.Thanku..
             System.out.println("Sorry TimeOut");
           else 
             System.out.println("Welcome");

        }
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you really *need* to store the timestamp as a string? I would suggest using a `long`, e.g. the result of calling `System.currentTimeMills()`... then format that into a string only for *diagnostic* purposes. Comparing `long` values is very easy :)

Alternatively, use [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) and keep the timestamps as [`Instant`](http://joda-time.sf.net/api-release/org/joda/time/Instant.html) values. That will make formatting easier, and you can use `isAfter`, `isAfterNow` etc for comparisons.

Answer (score 0):

You never want to use `String` to store/handle precise dates.

Usually you want to use `Date`, `Calendar` or even a more modern Java Date/Time API such as Joda Time or [JSR-310](http://today.java.net/article/2008/09/12/jsr-310-new-java-datetime-api) ([reference implementation here](http://java.net/projects/jsr-310/)).

If you simply want to use simple local timestamps, then a `long` might be sufficient:

```
long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

The advantage of a `long` is that you can use all the normal operations (addition, subtraction, equality checks, less-than-check) as you would do with any other numeric primitive type.

Answer (score 0):

Just Simplyfying your method returning long

```
public long getCurrentUtcTimestamp() 
{
    TimeZone utc = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC");
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(utc);
    return calendar.getTimeInMillis();
}
```